# Azure Storage does not show files uploaded as application/octet-stream or without content type

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have this code to upload to Azure Storage:

```
            BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(guid);
            var blobHttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders();
            if (contentType != null)
            {
                blobHttpHeaders.ContentType = contentType;
            }
            var response = blob.Upload(new MemoryStream(bytes), blobHttpHeaders);
```

If I set the `contentType` to `image/png`, then I can see that image in the Azure Portal, or via the blob link.

However, when I want to upload a file like a PDF, or an SVG file, and I set the `contentType` to `application/octet-stream` then I see code 201 and the **Created** response, yet I can't see the file in the Azure Portal, and when I use the blob link, I get 404.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code to upload a PDF file to a storage account with **contentType** set to **application/octet-stream** and uploaded a blob as pdf file successfully.

**Code :-**

```c
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "<connec_string>";
        string containerName = "<container_name>";
        string blobName = "<blob_name>";
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("<your_file>.pdf"); 

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        var blobHttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders
        {
            ContentType = "application/octet-stream" 
        };

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            blobClient.Upload(stream, blobHttpHeaders);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Blob uploaded successfully.");
    }
}
```

**Output** :

*The blob uploaded successfully as below:*

[image]

*The blob got uploaded to my storage account container in the Azure Portal and I clicked on download to check the data as below:-*

[image]

*The downloaded blob looks like below:*

[image]